# How to create nested Json data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which I convert into JSON. However, in JSON, I need to format a specific column with curly brackets.

The field time has value `"DAY=20220524"`, this has to be converted into `{"DAY":20170801}`

```
json data:
{"ID":200,"Type":"ABC","time":"DAY=20220524"}
{"ID":400,"Type":"ABC","time":"NOON=20220524"}

expected output:
{"ID":200,"Type":"ABC","time": {"DAY":20170801}}
{"ID":400,"Type":"ABC","time": {"DAY":20170801}}
```

I am not sure how do I do this. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

With the following `file.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": 200,
        "Type": "ABC",
        "time": "DAY=20220524"
    },
    {
        "ID": 400,
        "Type": "ABC",
        "time": "NOON=20220524"
    }
]
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.read_json("file.json").assign(
    time=lambda df_: df_["time"].apply(lambda x: f"{{{x}}}")
).to_json("new_file.json", orient="records")
```

In `new_file.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": 200,
        "Type": "ABC",
        "time": "{DAY=20220524}"
    },
    {
        "ID": 400,
        "Type": "ABC",
        "time": "{NOON=20220524}"
    }
]
```